# Load JavaScript into HTML after REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I have an older html/jquery webapp that I am looking at and I need to change it.  The original way the code was written was via Spring MVC.  An HTML page would make a call to a Servlet that would then return HTML to the client/browser.  This 'mypage.html' has several JS files that it loads in:

```
            <script src="js/file1.js"></script>
            <script src="js/file2.js"></script>
            <script src="js/file3.js"></script>
            <script src="js/file4.js"></script>
```

and so when the page is returned to the browser, the HTML page has replaced values and the JS then adds these scripts that know what to do with the data.

The way I am replacing it, gets rid of the MVC concept, and deals with this in a different way.  In my case, one page calls another HTML in an iFrame.  When the iframe is loaded, it then makes an Ajax/REST call to get data from the back-end ... and because we are doing it this way, the 4 javascript files are loaded, but do not have the data they need because it isn't there yet, so I see it as a bit of a race condition.

So, if I do something like ....

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : api_root + '/backed/api/mydataapi',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : JSON.stringify({
            queryid : queryId,
            token : tokenX
        }),
        success : function(data) {

            data1 = data.environment.data1;
            data2 = data.environment.data2;
            data3 = data.environment.data3;

            <script src="js/file1.js"></script>
            <script src="js/file2.js"></script>
            <script src="js/file3.js"></script>
            <script src="js/file4.js"></script>
        }
```

I don't think it works, but that is what I am shooting for.  If there is a better way to add these JS files to the page, but only after a successful REST call is made.   I am more of a back-end guy creating RESTful API's in Spring.  I am not a javascript person and haven't been for many years.  My employer would like to redo the whole UI in ReactJS, but we're not there yet.   In the meantime, I have to deal with this half-process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`$.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/).

If loading order is important will need to tweak this a bit since the requests are asynchronous and completion order is not guaranteed this way

```
 success : function(data) {

        data1 = data.environment.data1;
        data2 = data.environment.data2;
        data3 = data.environment.data3;

       $.getScript("js/file1.js");
       $.getScript("js/file2.js");
       ....
    }
```